# Robot Framework + MVC Grid+List+Dropdown

Tags: robotframework

I want to select a list from a dropdown, its a MVC grid implementation,Tried using Select From List, Select From List BY index keywords But not able to select the options present under the dropdown..the id of the `li` will change onclick of the selected item.

How can I  select contains from the list?

[image]

For Ex:

```
<li id="c2b79d1e-e14f-43cb-9a58-2c57231ef3a8" class="k-item k-state-focused k-state-selected" data-offset-index="0" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="true">Is equal to</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="1" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Is not equal to</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="2" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Starts with</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="3" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Contains</li>
```

Comment: You're citing `<li>` elements, but in the same time the source screenshot ia all `<span>`-s; so which of the two is actually used? _My bet is on the `span` :)_

Comment: Thanks Todor,Issue Resolved by jquery...